# Get required object from List…

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have one class `“Person”`………

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and suppose I have list `“listOfPerson”` which contain say 15 person…

```
List<Person> listOfPerson = new List<Person>();
```

Now I trying to get Object person form this List with Max Age…..

**Read Carefully I an not just need Max Age……
but entire object….so I can also access the name of the person with max Age…….**

Thanks………

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Person oldest = listOfPerson.OrderByDescending(person => person.Age).First();
```

From comments

> And suppose i
>   say....all the person with max
>   age...(list of person with max Age
>   from given list of person)? Thanks

In this case, it's worth it to find the maximum age and then filter on it. There are various approaches, but a straightforward method is

```
int maxAge = listOfPerson.Max(person => person.Age);
var oldestPeople = listOfPerson.Where(person => person.Age == maxAge); // .ToList()
```

Include the optional `ToList()` extension if it's important that the result be a list instead of an `IEnumerable<Person>`.

Comment: Ha, ha, you used "var"!  Beat me by five seconds again!  Exact same answer again!

Comment: Momentary slip. Happens on Fridays.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram,,And suppose i say....all the person with  max age...(list of person with max Age from given list of person)? Thanks...

Comment: @Anthony,.....is it possible to get List<int> which contain all the ages of person in the given list.......

Comment: @Anthony,.....i got it    List<int> ageList = (from person in list select person.Age).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

```
listOfPerson.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Age).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list is short then ordering and selecting the first (as previously mentioned) is probably the easiest.

If you have a longer list and sorting it starts to get slow (which is probably unlikely), you could write your own extension method to do it (I used MaxItem because I think just Max would conflict with existing LINQ methods, but I'm too lazy to find out).

```
public static T MaxItem<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, int> selector) {
    var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();

    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        // Return null/default on an empty list. Could choose to throw instead.
        return default(T);
    }

    T maxItem = enumerator.Current;
    int maxValue = selector(maxItem);

    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        var item = enumerator.Current;
        var value = selector(item);

        if (value > maxValue) {
            maxValue = value;
            maxItem = item;
        }
    }

    return maxItem;
}
```

Or, if you need to return all the maximum items:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MaxItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, int> selector) {
    var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();

    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }

    var maxItem = enumerator.Current;
    List<T> maxItems = new List<T>() { maxItem };
    int maxValue = selector(maxItem);

    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        var item = enumerator.Current;
        var value = selector(item);

        if (value > maxValue) {
            maxValue = value;
            maxItems = new List<T>() { item };
        } else if (value == maxValue) {
            maxItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return maxItems;
}
```